# BackupManager & BackupAgent in Android 2.2

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I've reviewed the docs and the sample BackupRestore app and written my own test app implementing `android:backupAgent`.  I extended the `BackupAgent` class because my main concern is being able to backup data from a database.  I can't seem to even make a simple proof-of-concept app work with this feature.

To make things exceptionally simple, I declared the `android:backupAgent` as `MyBackupAgent` in the manifest.  I then created a class MyBackupAgent.java, extending `BackupAgent`.  I then created overrides for the `onBackup()` and `onRestore()` methods within the `MyBackupAgent` class, just like in the examples and docs.  I added a `Log.i()` call to the very beginning of each function so that I could identify within LogCat when the functions were being called.  Likewise, I set breakpoints on both of these.  I then went on to implement my code to backup the database.

I created an emulator image using 2.2w/Google API's and even added a gmail account under Accounts & Sync.  Running through the adb commands to enable `bmgr`, backup the app, run the backup, uninstall the app, reinstall the app etc.... I never once get a message in the log file from the `Log.i()` command in either of the `onBackup()` or `onRestore()` functions.

I tried again on my Evo 4g running 2.2.  Same result.  It does not appear that the backup manager is calling the `onBackup()` and `onRestore()` functions in the `MyBackupAgent` class.

The only odd message I get in my logs is one from the `BackupManagerService` stating "Backup pass but e=true p=false", I believe in response to the ADB command to backup the app.

Any suggestions?  Am I wrong to assume that a `Log.i()` statement in the `onBackup()` and `onRestore()` functions would show up in LogCat?

Answer (score 8):

The output`Backup pass but e=true p=false` means the backup manager is enabled (`e=true`) but not provisioned (`p=false`).

It will only run backups if both of these conditions are met. So for some reason the backupmanager is not provisioned on your emulator image, after digging through the code I noticed it should get auto-provisioned during bootup ([DefaultActivity](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/development.git;a=blob;f=apps/SdkSetup/src/com/android/sdksetup/DefaultActivity.java;h=e87533dbc4c9c530ec2d2970fb1709e418891b8c;hb=HEAD))

```
I/ActivityManager(   73): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.sdksetup/.DefaultActivity } from pid 0
```

I just created a fresh emulator image, and it worked without problems there.

Answer (score 4):

Check your phone's settings. If the syncronization-service is disabled then backup via Data Backup API won't work.

Answer (score 3):

I also tried to use the "new" Backup Manager Service and always got following error messages:

```
12-01 09:58:54.420: WARN/BackupTransportService(9965): Unknown package in backup request: @pm@
12-01 09:58:54.450: WARN/BackupTransportService(9965): Not ready for backup request right now: [OperationScheduler: enabledState=false lastSuccess=2010-10-07/09:33:51 moratoriumSet=2010-12-01/09:53:32 moratorium=1970-01-01/01:00:00 trigger=1970-01-01/01:00:00]
12-01 09:58:54.450: WARN/PerformBackupThread(9965): Backup pass unsuccessful, restaging
```

Does anybody know what this means???

If I change backup transport to local version with following command

```
adb shell bmgr transport android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport
```

everything works well. So its not a problem of my code, I think...

Regards!