# How to check if Android Backup Service is supported?

Tags: android, android-backup-service

In accordance with [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html)

> Data backup is not guaranteed to be available on all Android-powered
>   devices.

How could I check in my code if it is supported or no?
I've tried to check what happens on my own device, but calling `dataChanged` says nothing except log message `Backup pass but e=true p=false` (explanation of the message is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4639259/604388)). The same happens with `adb shell bmgr backup my.package.name`. I would like to inform my application user if it is not supported.

Comment: Samsung Note 2 is not backing up files (FileBackupHelper). Sharedpreference is being backed up tho. I would like to know whether I made a mistake in my code or it is physically impossible to back up files in Galaxy Note 2 device

Comment: @coolcool1994, please star the issue I've raised about it - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81612

Answer (score 0):

The backup APIs are available on any device starting with Froyo, but unfortunately some products historically have accidentally broken various aspects of the system's behavior.  This should be much better as of Android M; there is considerably more focus on ensuring that backup/restore across the entire device population works well.